# user picks item from spinner, corresponding number in csv file shows intextview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have it so, when the user presses the fab, a cardview is added to the recyclerview layout. Inside each cardview that the user adds, is a spinner, checkbox edittext and textview. The spinner is populated by the first column in a csv file. The first column has item names, the second column has specific numbers relating to that product some of which can be the same

i had a previous similar app where when the user selects an item from the spinner, the coressponding number from the csv file shows in the textview. However that was without the recyclerviews or cardviews so I am trying to implement it in my code now (with recyclerview and cardviews)

However as I've been trying to implmenent that code in my current ProductAdapter (recyclerviewadapter) Code I have got an error:

**Compilation Errors:**

```
error: cannot find symbol method getResources()
```

It comes from this chunk of code

`InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
    CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
    final List<String>  mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();`

**Here is my full ProductAdapter.java code**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpinnerSelectedItem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();





    private SearchableSpinner spinner;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Product> productList;

    private Activity create;


    //TODO CODE FOR CSV FILE


    /*InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
    CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
    final List<String>  mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();*/


    InputStream inputStream = null;
    List<String>  mSpinnerItems = null;
    CSVFile csvFile = null;


    //TODO END OF CODE FOR CSV FILE

    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity) {
        create = activity;

    }


    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList) {
        // this.mCtx = mCtx;

       /* inputStream = create.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();*/

        create = activity;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(create);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        // //getting the product of the specified position




        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(create, R.layout.item_spinner_layout,
                Product.getSpinnerItemsList());
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int mPosition, long id) {
                mSpinnerSelectedItem.put(position, mPosition);


                TextView mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.mSpinnerText);


                //TODO CODE FOR GETTING AISLE NUMBER AND PUTTING IT IN THE TEXTVIEW
                String currentItem = mSpinnerItems.get(position);
                String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                holder.textView5.setText(aisleNumber);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        if (mSpinnerSelectedItem.containsKey(position)) {
            holder.spinner.setSelection(mSpinnerSelectedItem.get(position));
        }


        holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create);


                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity


                                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                                holder.spinner.setSelection(0);



                                productList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                                Toast.makeText(create, "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });





    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }


    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SearchableSpinner spinner;
        EditText editText;
        TextView textView5;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        View rootView;


        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            rootView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);


            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // makes the set disappear when checkbox is ticked.
                    if(isChecked){

                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                        spinner.setSelection(0);

                        productList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());



                        Toast.makeText(create, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });



        }

        public View getView() {
            return rootView;
        }

    }

    //TODO CODE FOR CSV FILE
    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");

                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);

                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }


}
```

**create.java code which is my mainactivity where the cards are added  and the fab is etc**

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {



    //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    Product mProduct;
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpinnerSelectedItem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);


        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
         CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);

       final List<String>  mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();


        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(new Product(mSpinnerItems, "Test Edit Text",false, "Text String 2"));




      final ProductAdapter  adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);

        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
             findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                productList.add(mProduct);
                if(adapter != null)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                //Handle the empty adapter here

            }
        });









        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);






    }



    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable

                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);

                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter has know idea about `getResources()`. This needs to come from an `Activity` or `Context` object. So do this:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
List<String>  mSpinnerItems = null;
CSVFile csvFile = null;
```

then in your public `ProductAdapter()` method initialize the `InputStream` properly.

```
public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList) {
    create = activity;
    //INFO:: Now initialize the InputStream
    inputStream = create.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
    csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
    mSpinnerItems = csvFile.read();
    this.productList = productList;
}
```

Of course you could create a `string-array` resource and fill the spinner view with that.

```
<string-array name="my_values">
    <item>Hello</item>
    <item>World</item>
    <item>Back</item>
    <item>Again</item>
</string-array>
```

Then in the layout file:

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/my_values"
    />
```

.

---

EDIT

With the updated code you can remove:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
List<String>  mSpinnerItems = null;
CSVFile csvFile = null;
```

From the `ProductAdapter`.

The `NullPointerException` error occurring at line:

```
String currentItem = mSpinnerItems.get(position);
```

is caused because `mSpinnerItems` is no longer being used and is set to `null`. So, in order to get the value of the selection in the spinner do this:

```
    holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int mPosition, long id) {
            mSpinnerSelectedItem.put(position, mPosition);

            TextView mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.mSpinnerText);


            //TODO CODE FOR GETTING AISLE NUMBER AND PUTTING IT IN THE TEXTVIEW
            //SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner)view;
            String currentItem = holder.spinner.getItemAtPosition(mPosition).toString();
            // or try
            // spinner.getAdapter.getItem(mPosition).toString();
            String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
            holder.textView5.setText(aisleNumber);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

.

---

NEW EDIT:

in the `ProductAdapter` use this:

```
 public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList, HashMap<String, String> numberList) {
        numberItemValues = numberList;
        create = activity;
        this.productList = productList;
    }
```

and change this line in the "create"  `Activity`:

```
final ProductAdapter  adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList, numberItemValues);
```

Comment: hi thanks for that, unfortunately I encountered an error though, please see post I have edited it under the heading of your username

Comment: hello? @Barns ,.

Comment: Do I keep ```InputStream inputStream = null;
    List<String>  mSpinnerItems = null;
    CSVFile csvFile = null;```

Comment: @GrandSkunk :: You got the `NullPointerException` because you used  `inputStream = create.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);` before use set "create"  to the "activity" ->`create = activity;` You didn't follow my code example as it needed to be. None the less you have moved that code to your "create" `Activity`--which I think was a good decision.

Comment: @GrandSkunk :: There is no need to keep `InputStream inputStream = null; List<String> mSpinnerItems = null; CSVFile csvFile = null;` in the `ProductAdapter` class -- you can remove it if you have no references to it in your `ProductAdapter`

Comment: Ok but the thing is, for my create activity which is mymain activity where all cardviews are added nstuff, I don't think I need the csv code there because that should all be at the adapter right? Anyways I tried what you said but got an error https://pastebin.com/5xuATEqK at this line                 `String currentItem = mSpinnerItems.get(position);` in the ProductAdapter code..  I'll update my code in the post now for both classes

Comment: ah ok. could you put that in the answer so it's easier to read

Comment: I will try it now

Comment: for this line                 `String currentItem = spinner.getItemAtPosition(mPosition);` it says incompatible types  required string, found object

Comment: I get error on this line `Spinner spinner = (Spinner)view;` https://pastebin.com/CeBufHvC

Comment: @GrandSkunk :: Sorry-- I didn't see that it was a `SearchableSpinner`! Check the answer, now. I am unfamiliar with `SearchableSpinner`.. so you will have to check if it has a `getItemAtPosition` or a `getAdapter.getItem()` method

Comment: so I change `Spinner spinner = (Spinner)view;` to  `SearchableSpinner spinner = (Spinner)view;`?

Comment: @GrandSkunk :: look again. It should be `SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner)view;`

Comment: first line u said didnt work. I tried the getAdapter line but it  cannot resolve symbol getAdapter. Do I put the name of the adpater i,e ProductAdapter

Comment: oh wait its gedadapter()

Comment: I get the same error on this line                 SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner)view;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181122/discussion-between-grand-skunk-and-barns).